# iOS / Core Data Entity Relationships with Pre-Defined Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two Objective-C Core Data entities - say Person and Nationality. Person would have a To-One relationship with Nationality, whilst Nationality would have a To-Many relationship with Person. Also, Person class can have any number of objects / rows, whereas Nationality would have a pre-defined list of 200 odd instances. So Person should not be able to assign a nationality to itself other than those 200 objects.

Can someone advise please how would we code this out or in case there is a sample code available? Afraid I dont seem to be able to get a start on how to leverage setValue: forKey: here...

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got a ManagedObjectModel mapped out? Also have you looked into [pre-loading data into CoreData](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)?

Comment: Your question is too broad and needs to be broken down. You also need to show what you have so far in terms of the data model, the source data to preload, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your Nationality entity has a "name" attribute that uniquely identifies that nationality.  You can provide any manner of UI to get this from the user.  It can be typing in a string or fetching all nationalities and putting them in a table or some kind of picker.

If you want all nationalities, that's easy.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Nationality"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *nationalities = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (nationalities == nil) {
    // handle error
} else {
    // You now have an array of all Nationality entities that can be used
    // in some UI element to allow a specific one to be picked
}
```

If you want to look it up based on a string for the name...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Nationality"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", nationalityName];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
NSArray *nationalities = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (nationalities == nil) {
    // handle error
} else {
    NSManagedObject *nationality = [nationalities firstObject];
    // If non-nil, it will be the nationality object you desire
}
```

Creating the person and assigning its nationality is also straight forward...

```
if (nationality) {
    NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    // Set any attributes of the Person entity
    [person setValue:@"Fred Flintstone" forKey:@"name"];

    // Assign its nationality, and as long as the relationship is setup with
    // inverse relationships, the inverse will be automatically assigned
    [person setValue:nationality forKey:@"nationality"];
}
```